# Ubuntu 22.04 shows systemd-journald error after I wake up from suspend

Tags: tty, crash

After I wake up my computer(Mi notebook ultra 2021) from suspend
it doesn't let me click the field where the password needs to be entered.
I have to restart by pressing ctrl + alt + printscn + REISUB.

Going to tty by pressing ctrl +alt +f5 shows the following 3 error in a loop at line speed :

Failed to rotate /var/log/jounal/[computer-id]/system.journal : Input/output error

Failed to rotate /var/log/jounal/[computer-id]/user-1000.journal : Input/output error

Failed to write entry despite vacuuming, ignoring : Input/ output error

What can I do to fix it?

[image: tty5 screen after waking up from sleep]